# google map javascript api transit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

My requirement is, need to show all Transit Bus stations of a particular location(like state, city) and should able to mark only transit bus stations and show the infoWindow of that Transit Bus station using google map javascript api.

below is my html code, javascript marker logic also marks all the locations on the map i need to mark only transit bus stations

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add/Remove Markers</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 50%;
            width:50%;
            position:inherit !important;
            margin-top:50px !important;
        }

        #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 25%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        #map > div{
            height:70% !important;
            width:70% !important;
            margin-top:50px !important;
        }

        a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"]{
            display: none !important;
        }

        .gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span, .gm-style-cc div {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .gmnoprint div {
            background: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
        <input onclick="clearMarkers();" type=button value="Hide Markers">
        <input onclick="showMarkers();" type=button value="Show All Markers">
        <input onclick="deleteMarkers();" type=button value="Delete Markers">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p>Click on the map to add markers.</p>
    <script>

      // In the following example, markers appear when the user clicks on the map.
      // The markers are stored in an array.
      // The user can then click an option to hide, show or delete the markers.
      var map;
      var markers = [];

      function initMap() {
        var haightAshbury = {lat: 37.769, lng: -122.446};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: haightAshbury,
          disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
        map.addListener('click', function (event) {
          addMarker(event.latLng);
        });

        // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
        addMarker(haightAshbury);
      }

      // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);

        //This code is to remove the marker from the map and the array
        marker.addListener('click', function (e) {
            var latIndex = markers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lat() == e.latLng.lat());
            var lngIndex = markers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lng() == e.latLng.lng());

            if ((latIndex != -1 && lngIndex != -1) && (latIndex == lngIndex)) {
                markers[latIndex].setMap(null); // To remove the marker from the Map
                markers.splice(latIndex, 1); // to remove the marker from the list of array
            }            
        });


        marker.addListener('mouseover', function (e) {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

          // assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
        marker.addListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            infowindow.close();
        });
      }

      // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
      function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }

      // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
      function clearMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(null);
      }

      // Shows any markers currently in the array.
      function showMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(map);
      }

      // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
      function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
        markers = [];
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
      var map;
      var infowindow;
      var service;
      var markers = [];
      var availableMarkers = [];
      var unAvailableMarkers = [];
      var selectedMarkers = [];
      var globalResults = [];
      function initialize(lat,lng)
      {
        var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: origin,
          zoom: 15,
          disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        var request = {
          location: origin,
          radius: 2500,
          types: ['bus_station']
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request, callback);

        map.addListener('click', function (event) {
            initialize(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng())
        });
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              globalResults = results;
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  if (i < 11)
                      createMarker(results[i], 'green');
                  else
                      createMarker(results[i], 'red');
              }
          }
      }

      function createMarker(place,color) {
          var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
          var icon;

          if (color == 'green')
              icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
          else if (color == 'red')
              icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
          else
              icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
          resizeIcon = icon;

          var marker = null;
          if (color == 'green') {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: place.geometry.location,
                  icon: resizeIcon
              });
              availableMarkers.push(marker);
          }
          else if (color == 'red') {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: place.geometry.location,
                  icon: resizeIcon
              });
              unAvailableMarkers.push(marker);
          }
          else {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: place.geometry.location,
                  icon: resizeIcon
              });
              selectedMarkers.push(marker);
          }

          markers.push(marker);

          var content = '<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                'Place ID: ' + place.place_id;
                
          var more_content = '<img src="../Content/Images/1475150806_map-marker.png"/>'; // this is to show the image r any additional content

          //make a request for further details
          service.getDetails({ reference: place.reference }, function (place, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                  more_content = '<hr/><strong><a href="' + place.url + '" target="details">Details</a>';

                  if (place.website) {
                      more_content += '<br/><br/><strong><a href="' + place.website + '" target="details">' + place.website + '</a>';
                  }
              }
          });


          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
              //infowindow.setContent(content + more_content);
              infowindow.setContent(content);
              infowindow.open(map, this);
          });

            // assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
          //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (e) {
          //    infowindow.close();
          //});

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {

              var latIndex = markers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lat() == e.latLng.lat());
              var lngIndex = markers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lng() == e.latLng.lng());

              var isAvailLat = availableMarkers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lat() == e.latLng.lat());
              var isAvailLng = availableMarkers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lng() == e.latLng.lng());


              var isUnAvailLat = unAvailableMarkers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lat() == e.latLng.lat());
              var isUnAvailLng = unAvailableMarkers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lng() == e.latLng.lng());

              var isSelectedLat = selectedMarkers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lat() == e.latLng.lat());
              var isSelectedLng = selectedMarkers.findIndex(x=>x.position.lng() == e.latLng.lng());

              if ((latIndex != -1 && lngIndex != -1) && (latIndex == lngIndex)) {

                  if ((isSelectedLat != -1 && isSelectedLng != -1) && (isSelectedLat == isSelectedLng)) {
                      selectedMarkers.splice(isSelectedLat, 1);
                      availableMarkers.push(markers[latIndex]);
                      marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
                  }
                  else if ((isAvailLat != -1 && isAvailLng != -1) && (isAvailLat == isAvailLng)) {
                      availableMarkers.splice(isAvailLat, 1);
                      selectedMarkers.push(markers[latIndex]);
                      marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png');
                  }
                  else if ((isUnAvailLat != -1 && isUnAvailLng != -1) && (isUnAvailLat == isUnAvailLng)) {
                      alert('This Transit is not avaliable, pls select a valid transit');
                  }
                  
              }
          });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { initialize(39.759444, -84.191667); });
```

```css
        /*These styles area added to hide the google footer*/ 
        a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"] {
            display: none !important;
        }

        a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"] {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span, .gm-style-cc {
            display: none;
        }
        .gmnoprint div {
            background: none !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Transit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height:600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```